# Pandas - Take average value given the same year but year is divided into quarters

Tags: python, pandas

The dataset I'm working with has the years split into quarters. I'd like to get the average education rates per year per specific country.

In my mind it would look something like: If year is 1999.xx then mean(educrate).

The data looks like:

```
Country     Year      Educ Rate
USA         1999.00   95
USA         1999.25   96
USA         1999.50   97
USA         1999.75   95
USA         2000.00   99
Argentina   1999.00   88
Argentina   1999.25   86
Argentina   1999.50   88
Argentina   1999.75   89
Argentina   2000.00   90
```

I'd greatly appreciate any tips/advice!

Thanks.

Comment: The image that you provided is dark. Please post the sample dataset not as image but as text.

Comment: you might want to research `pandas` aggregate data.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to round the years down using `.apply(math.floor)`. After this, you could then group by country and year and aggregate on means.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['USA', 1999.0, 95],
                        ['USA', 1999.25, 96],
                        ['USA', 1999.5, 97],
                        ['USA', 1999.75, 95],
                        ['USA', 2000.0, 99],
                        ['Argentina', 1999.0, 88],
                        ['Argentina', 1999.25, 86],
                        ['Argentina', 1999.5, 88],
                        ['Argentina', 1999.75, 89],
                        ['Argentina', 2000.0, 90],
                       ],
                  columns=['Country', 'Year', 'Educ_rate'])
# round year down
df['Year'] = (df['Year']).apply(math.floor)

# aggregate means
df_agg = df.groupby(['Country', 'Year']).agg('mean')
```

Would give:

```
# print(df_agg)
                Educ_rate
Country   Year           
Argentina 1999      87.75
          2000      90.00
USA       1999      95.75
          2000      99.00
```

Comment: Thanks! This is useful - the only thing is that it says : "TypeError: must be real number, not str" . I've tried converting it to an int or a float but neither helps. Any suggestions?

Please know: the data is to the 15th decimal point. Does this have an impact?

Comment: The precision of the decimal shouldn't matter. Without access to the data, it's difficult, but often problems like you're describing are down to stray NA values that don't convert well. For example:
`df['Year'] = df['Year'].replace("na", np.NaN)`
`df['Year'] = df['Year'].astype('float')`

Answer (score 0):

you need to split with the '.' and then groupby by year and country

```
    tmp = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2],
     'b': ['2015.00','2015.00', '2015.25', '2015.50', '2016.00','2016.00', '2016.25', '2016.50',
           '2017.00', '2017.00'],
     'c': [2,3,4,5,7,3,4,5,3,2]})

    tmp['year'] = tmp['b'].apply(lambda x: x.split('.')[0])
    tmp['mean'] = tmp.groupby(['a', 'year'])['c'].transform('mean')
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm almost there. The first line, starting with: " tmp['year'] = ... " works. But with the second line it indicates "DataError: No numeric types to aggregate". I've changed your code to work with my variables. It looks like this:

 df['mean'] = df.groupby(['Country', 'Year'])['educ'].transform('mean')

Comment: What is the dtype of the 'educ' variable?

Comment: dtype for educ is "Object."

Comment: Than you should add a line after the code that run like this  ```df['educ'] = df['educ'].astype(float)```

Comment: I really appreciate your help! I have this:

    df['educ'] = df['educ'].astype(float)
    df['Year'] = df['Year'].apply(lambda x: x.split('.')[0])
    df['mean'] = df.groupby(['Country', 'Year'])['educ'].transform('mean')
    return df

This gives:

"ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'NA'"

Do you know why?

Comment: If you check all the unique values of Educ do you see only numeric like values?

Comment: They are numerical except for one. I'm removing this now and I'll try again.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much.

The code is:

df['Educ'] = df['Educ'].astype(float)
    df['Year'] = df['Year'].apply(lambda x: x.split('.')[0])
    df['mean'] = df.groupby(['Country', 'Year'])['Educ'].transform('mean')